# Blank preview in chrome when using JQuery and window.print

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery and I am using Window.Print function but it shows blank preview in chrome. This is my sample code: any idea what am I doing wrong in my code?

```
  jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index/print",
            dataType: 'text',
            data:data,
            success: function(res) { 
            var w = window.open(document.URL, '_blank', "location=No,height=1000,width=700,scrollbars=yes,status=yes" );
             w.document.write(res);
             alert(res);
              w.print();
               setTimeout(function(){w.close();}, 2);

      }
    });
```

Comment: So this is a `.php` file? A browser will not be able to render `<?php ?>` tags to create the URL

Comment: but the same function is working on firefox

Comment: and the res contains the data also just the file preview shows blank page

Comment: If you use the debugger from browser how does the URL look like? maybe you just lucky in FF cause it's an empty string

Comment: sir ,have used it throgh out the program it works fine.i am just having issue why the preview page of print shows blank page ..if i alert the data it shows  whole part